# Google Cloud Shell permission denied Maven build

Tags: java, maven, cloud, google-cloud-shell

I need help with the Google Cloud. I am trying to clean and package a Java Maven project in the Google Cloud shell but ran into this error

"/home/user/testapp/milestonejava3-master/mvnw" clean -f "/home/user/testapp/milestonejava3-master/pom.xml"
bash: /user/testapp/milestonejava3-master/mvnw: Permission denied

As listed above I ran the clean command and was got the Permission denied! I'm pretty new to using the shell, and tried looking up ways to permit permission but most commands are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

figured out the proper command

mvn clean package